# I fixed grub error after ubuntu install with cd fix, but

Tags: boot, windows-xp

I fixed grub error after ubuntu install with cd fix, but now I am only booting to xp. How do I get ubuntu to boot ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to ([boot from cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)) then you will have successfully booted Ubuntu.

However if you are trying to install Ubuntu if you could please include more information:

1) what the partitions look like on your HD in ubuntu terminal this is done by entering in the command (`sudo fdisk -l`) or in windows commandline by entering (`diskpart`)

2) describe more completely what you have done

3) Are you trying to install Ubuntu by itself, or are you trying to Dual Boot?

If you are trying to dual boot have you followed information similar to [this?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)